# Post JDK1.8 to JDK 11 Migration facing issue for SOAP Webservice call "Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace"

Tags: web-services, java-11

Post migration to JDK 11 our application calls SOAP Webservice . We are facing below runtime issue as highlighted below in the JBOSS Server Log.

> 11:20:46,267 INFO
> [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext]
> (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) Refreshing Root
> WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Nov 08 11:20:46 IST 2023];
> root of context hierarchy11:20:46,350 INFO
> [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader]
> (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) Loading XML bean definitions from
> ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]11:20:49,478
> ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService
> Thread Pool -- 76)Context initialization failed:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:Configuration
> problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema
> namespace
> [http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services\]Offending
> resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
>
> ```
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
> [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
> [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
> [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:316)
> [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1420)
> [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1413)
> [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
> [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
> [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
> [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
> [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
> [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
> [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
> [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
> [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
> [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
> [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
> [org.springframework.web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
> [org.springframework.web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
> [org.springframework.context-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:530)
> [org.springframework.context-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:444)
> [org.springframework.context-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
> [org.springframework.web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
> [org.springframework.web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]at
> org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
> [org.springframework.web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
> ```

Looking forward for the solution on this issue .